# Setting IP route on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, iptables

Since days I am trying to find out how to change the ip route of my Ubuntu correctly.
I know I have to edit `/etc/network/interfaces`, but can't find out how to do it correctly.

My network is a little complicated. I have data sticks connected that I use on a different computer. 
But I do not like Ubuntu to use them himself.

In other words I would like is to always use `enp31s0` (lan)
and never use any other way.
So if lan fails ubuntu should have no internet connection.

```
ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp31s0  src 192.168.0.107  metric 202 
default via 192.168.30.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.30.2  metric 203 
default via 192.168.30.5 dev eth1  src 192.168.30.6  metric 204 
default via 192.168.30.53 dev eth2  src 192.168.30.54  metric 205
default via 192.168.30.9 dev eth3  src 192.168.30.10  metric 206
default via 192.168.30.61 dev eth7  src 192.168.30.62  metric 210
default via 192.168.30.13 dev eth9  src 192.168.30.14  metric 212
default via 192.168.30.17 dev eth10  src 192.168.30.18  metric 213
default via 192.168.30.29 dev eth13  src 192.168.30.30  metric 216
default via 192.168.30.21 dev eth14  src 192.168.30.22  metric 218
default via 192.168.30.25 dev eth17  src 192.168.30.26  metric 222
default via 192.168.30.37 dev eth18  src 192.168.30.38  metric 223
default via 192.168.30.33 dev eth19  src 192.168.30.34  metric 224
default via 192.168.30.41 dev eth20  src 192.168.30.42  metric 225
default via 192.168.30.45 dev eth21  src 192.168.30.46  metric 227
default via 192.168.30.49 dev rename28  src 192.168.30.50  metric 228
default via 192.168.30.57 dev eth4  src 192.168.30.58  metric 264
default via 192.168.30.93 dev rename82  src 192.168.30.94  metric 282
default via 192.168.30.97 dev rename94  src 192.168.30.98  metric 294
default via 192.168.30.73 dev rename95  src 192.168.30.74  metric 295
default via 192.168.30.77 dev rename96  src 192.168.30.78  metric 296
default via 192.168.30.69 dev rename97  src 192.168.30.70  metric 297
default via 192.168.30.85 dev enx001e101f0000  src 192.168.30.86  metric 298 
default via 192.168.30.81 dev rename100  src 192.168.30.82  metric 300
default via 192.168.30.89 dev rename101  src 192.168.30.90  metric 301
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.5
10.8.1.0/24 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.1.2
10.8.6.0/24 dev tun2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.6.6
169.254.0.0/16 dev tun1  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp31s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.107  metric 202 
192.168.30.0/30 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.2  metric 203 
192.168.30.4/30 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.6  metric 204 
192.168.30.8/30 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.10  metric 206 
192.168.30.12/30 dev eth9  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.14  metric 212 
192.168.30.16/30 dev eth10  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.18  metric 213 
192.168.30.20/30 dev eth14  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.22  metric 218 
192.168.30.24/30 dev eth17  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.26  metric 222 
192.168.30.28/30 dev eth13  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.30  metric 216 
192.168.30.32/30 dev eth19  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.34  metric 224 
192.168.30.36/30 dev eth18  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.38  metric 223 
192.168.30.40/30 dev eth20  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.42  metric 225 
192.168.30.44/30 dev eth21  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.46  metric 227 
192.168.30.48/30 dev rename28  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.50  metric 228 
192.168.30.52/30 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.54  metric 205 
192.168.30.56/30 dev eth4  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.58  metric 100 
192.168.30.56/30 dev eth4  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.58  metric 264 
192.168.30.60/30 dev eth7  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.62  metric 210 
192.168.30.64/30 dev rename102  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.66  metric 302 
192.168.30.68/30 dev rename97  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.70  metric 297 
192.168.30.72/30 dev rename95  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.74  metric 295 
192.168.30.76/30 dev rename96  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.78  metric 296 
192.168.30.80/30 dev rename100  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.82  metric 300 
192.168.30.84/30 dev enx001e101f0000  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.86  metric 298 
192.168.30.88/30 dev rename101  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.90  metric 301 
192.168.30.92/30 dev rename82  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.94  metric 282 
192.168.30.96/30 dev rename94  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.98  metric 294
```

Answer (score 1):

You should go for route `default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp31s0` and remove all other routes in your routing table. Use `ip route del` to remove them. If the other routes are providing you an internet access and are attached via different metric, then the best way is to disconnect the interface.

Another option is to use iptables to drop the packets to `0.0.0.0` destinated to a specific interface which makes the thing even more complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! 
So highly appreciated because I have been trying for days..

Removing them with up route del is not permanent, is it?
So they will come back as default after reboot.

Yes, every single one of them provides internet access. 
And I can surf through those Data Sticks on my VPS. 
My lan connection sends those packages to my VPS but I do not want that my Ubuntu ever uses one of them to access the internet.
Because then one random datastick send all the packages of all other datasticks to my VPS and that datastick fails because its connection is too slow

Comment: The best option is to remove the unnecessary data connection. But if you want to keep them for surfing then the iptables is the way to go. You can also create two VLANs, one for the VPS data connection, second for the private data connection and define the iptables rules for each VLAN interface separately.